Do we renormalize couplings when numerically studying spin systems in the limit of large system size?
I'm trying to understand whether one should renormalize coupling constants when simulating spin systems with a variable number of lattice sites.
In lattice HEP calculations, for example, one typically first fixes the total physical system size and then studies this box at a higher and higher resolution by increasing the number of lattice sites. However, since we want to to reach a certain continuous theory, increasing the number of lattice sites has to be accompanied with adjustment of coupling constants.
In solid state physics, however, we do have some fundamental minimal lattice spacing (e.g., distance between the atoms of a solid). When increasing the number of sites in the simulation, we can take two perspectives:

The two spins represent the two elementary DOFs, and we are quite literally trying to consider more and more of these. Apparently no renormalization needed.

Spins represent some averaged configurations of finite-sized domains, and increasing the number of spins correspond to studying the same physical volume at a higher resolution, and thus requires renormalization.


Which of these is typically used? Which one do people call thermodynamic limit? Which one should I use if I want to study the thermodynamic limit and also extrapolate to the large system size?

Wilsonian renormalisation came from condensed matter to HEP. Of course it is used; not just for critical phenomena where the renormalisation is most useful, but also for the faster convergence. Nobody wants to sum many terms for everything, when a much faster series suffices.

OK, so if someone shows me a phase diagram on which each point is obtained by "extrapolating to the thermodynamic limit", should I assume that they were renormalizing the coupling constant for each system size?

You cannot make that assumption. Maybe it is not done. The text should make it clear.
